# Can you filter JSON with multiple keys in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, json

Can you filter based on multiple keys in the Firefox JSON viewer? Lets say I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "obj": [{
            "online": true,
            "count": 5,
            "timeout": 10
        },
        {
            "online": false,
            "count": 55,
            "timeout": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

If I enter `online` in the `Filter JSON` text area it works and all I see is the `online` key.

What if I want to see `online` and `timeout`? Entering `online, timeout` in the `Filter JSON` shows nothing. `online || timeout` shows nothing. `online OR timeout` shows nothing. Nothing I try works.

Is it possible to filter the JSON based on multiple keys? I haven't had much luck searching and documentation wise all I can really find is [this Mozilla page](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/json_viewer/index.html), but it barely has any useful information.

Comment: *Partial* workaround: open a second instance of the file in a new tab or in a new Firefox instance. Separate filters can be applied to each. Of course, that does not show the two lines in *relation* to each other. Perhaps another JSON viewer offers better filtering: https://listoffreeware.com/8-best-free-json-viewer-software-windows/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the keys not being in relation to each other is the main issue with that workaround. I currently get by with the raw JSON and `Sublime Text` regex. I was hoping I was missing something with the filtering as I plan to disable it if there's no solution there.